# Face recognition for MacOS login

Tags: macos, authentication, face-recognition

Is it possible to develop an application for MACOS login by face recognition. I know there are some face recognition libraries for MACOS. The question which I couldn't find any information is if the MACOS allows an alternative login. My app must replace MACOS login. Is there any API or project sample that extend login in MACOS? I only found Keylemon app for MAC login but couldn't find any chance to use it yet. If they do such thing, it is possible I think but I can't find any resources about the development.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by looking at the OS X [Authorization services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html). In particular, the Authorization plugin reference, which is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/AuthorizationPluginRef/Reference/reference.html).